# Maven dependencyset unpack to other assembly

Tags: java, file, maven

I have the following maven script:

```
<dependencySet>
            <includes>
                <include>groupId:artifactId</include>
            </includes>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <unpackOptions>
                <includes>
                    <include>parentFolder/subFolder/dynamicFolder/*.*</include>
                </includes>
            </unpackOptions>
            <outputDirectory>outFolder/outSubFolder/</outputDirectory>
        </dependencySet>
```

I expect my dependency to be unpacked under the folder

> /outFolder/outSubFolder/**

But what i get is :

> /outFolder/outSubFolder/parentFolder/subFolder/dynamicFolder/**

Anyone know what I'm missing here?

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't rearrange directories, it just copies files. So it works as expected.

Comment: so what should i do to make it work as i want?